# pandas python: how to append based on a condition of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Say i have a simple data frame:

```
student_id    name   age   address
student1       a     12      us
student2       b     13      us
student3       c     13      uk
```

I want to append the values of age and address to the name if there is a condition, lets say concatenate age and address to name if age is 13, like so:

```
student_id    name   age   address
student1       a     12      us
student2       b     13      us
student3       c     13      uk
             b-13-us
             c-13-uk
```

How do I implement this to my current dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter columns by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and mask  by[`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), convert to strings and join together:

```
s = df.loc[df['age'].eq(13), ['name','age','address']].astype(str).agg('-'.join, 1)
```

Then create one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), if want repalce all columns to empty strings add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) (also `age` column is now mixed - numeric and strings) and add new rows by [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df1 = s.to_frame('name').reindex(df.columns, fill_value='', axis=1)
df = df.append(df1, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  student_id     name age address
0   student1        a  12      us
1   student2        b  13      us
2   student3        c  13      uk
3             b-13-us            
4             c-13-uk
```

For new format is processing each column separately:

```
df0 = df[df['age'].eq(13)].copy()
s = df0['name'] + ' (' + df0['age'].astype(str) + '-' + df0['address'] + ')'
df1 = s.to_frame('name').reindex(df.columns, fill_value='', axis=1)
df = df.append(df1, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  student_id       name age address
0   student1          a  12      us
1   student2          b  13      us
2   student3          c  13      uk
3             b (13-us)            
4             c (13-uk)
```

Comment: hi thank you so much! it worked perfectly! will the .join work if i do the following format instead: 'b (13-16)' instead of 'b-13-us'?

Comment: @pancakes - value `16` is same for each appended values?

Comment: sorry it was a typo. it's supposed to be 'b (13-us)'

Comment: Hi sorry one more thing! What if you wanted to keep the index in student_id? like for the newly appended values, you wanted it to be student4 and student5 respectively?

Comment: @pancakes - Is possible use `df['student'] = 'student' + (df.index + 1).astype(str)` ? after my solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211081/discussion-between-pancakes-and-jezrael).